# How to update the second to last entry in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

Does anyone have an idea how I can update, for example, a second to last entry?

For example, I have a Banned column in a Users table. I have to set Banned = 1 for the second to last account.

```
UPDATE Users SET Banned = '1' WHERE LIMIT 2,1
```

That's not working. Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Maybe it's possible to do one long query first. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT 2,1
```

And then, using this query somehow update Banned column?

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is an id auto-increment column  in users table you can try this one

```
UPDATE Users SET Banned = '1' WHERE id =
(SELECT t.id FROM (SELECT id FROM Users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1) t )
```

`ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,1` for second last account